# Binance Coin on Binance and why there are premiums on certain pairs?

Tags: economics

I need a little help understanding the dynamics of the Binance Coin (BNB) market on Binance. Why does BNB equate to almost exactly market price of IOTA? But when converting BNB to Ethereum, Bitcoin or USD you get 15 percent more?

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation I can think of here is that you pay less fees (50% reduction) using BNB Binance coins than any others, which is the main incentive to use them. You will need to be more specific in giving examples to explain what you mean by 15%.

Comment: Aboose I see you everywhere..famous iotian.....thanks for taking the time to read my question. I figured it out. I am so into the big picture i forgot how to do 3rd grade math ...thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I am glad you were able to figure it out!